# jquery tablesorter how to ignore a row from the sort

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I've got a bit of a problem with my table sorter sort at the moment. The issue is that I am sorting my time but when the column contains n/a I would like it to appear at the end of the sort. Can anyone help me achieve this please?

[image]

Here is my sort code...

```
$("#myStoreStatus").tablesorter({
    sortList: [[2,1],[8,0],[0,0]],
    stripingRowClass: ['even','odd'],
    stripeRowsOnStartUp: true,
    widthFixed: false, 
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    dateFormat: "uk",
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: 'digit' } // column number, type
    }
});
```

Comment: check documentation, maybe have some html tag like this `data-order="10"`, so your html code will looks like this `<td data-order="10">Ten</td>`. In that case system will take `data-order` for sorting, and for N/A you can enter 23:59 value so will appear at bottom.

Comment: @Davor this would not work if the sorting order is changed.

Comment: well, http://datatables.net/ have this option so i suggested to look. maybe also tablesorter have this option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could understand the problem is that you want the n/a rows to appear always at the end, even if the sorting order for the time column is changed.

Here is one possible option.

```js
$("#myStoreStatus").tablesorter({
    sortList: [[2,1],[8,0],[0,0]],
    stripingRowClass: ['even','odd'],
    stripeRowsOnStartUp: true,
    widthFixed: false, 
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    dateFormat: "uk",
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: 'digit' } // column number, type
    },

    textExtraction: function (node) {
        if (($(node).index()==8) && ($(node).text().toLowerCase()=='n/a'))
            $(node).parent().addClass('jsnamark');
        return $(node).text();
    }

}).bind('sortEnd' function () {
    $(this).append($(this).find('.jsnamark'));
});
```

Now, what this peace is doing is quite simple. It uses textExtraction function to check if the 8th (time) cell has the 'n/a' value. If it does then it adds a jsnamark class to its row. (you can also do the same thing in a several different ways with jQuery or from the server side if you are serving page with a server script).

When the sorting is done it reappends the rows that have the jsnamark class to the end of the table.

Comment: +1 Nice work. The only issue I can see that might occur is if the table data gets modified and the 'n/a' gets replaced by a number. Also, this check should make sure it's in lower case `$(node).text().toLowerCase()=='n/a'`

Comment: @Mottie both very true

Comment: Check this out for changing the cell values. I guess that if you use this to trigger updateCell it would redo the textExtraction. However I would then add "else $(node).parent().removeClass('jsnamark')"  link: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-update-cell.html

Comment: great solution. I will use this over and over again in the next few months. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to also check out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

There is a built-in option where you can set how string values (e.g. "N/A") sort within numerical columns - see [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers-digits-strings.html).

If you are using the original tablesorter, you can use the `textExtraction` option to replace `N/A` with an empty string; or use @Jadran's code which would also work.